# Why does Photoshop close when I try to open a File via 'Desktop' Shortcut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, desktop, file-shortcut, photoshop-cs6

I have a variety of Photoshop files I have saved on my Desktop.  Whenever I try to open these files within Photoshop, via `File > Open > Desktop Shortcut Button` (as per below image), the Photoshop programme closes.

[image]

If I head to the Desktop via `File > Open > Computer > C: > Users > Desktop > Photoshop File`, I have no problems at all in opening the relevant Photoshop file.

Where would I start in finding out what is causing this 'Shortcut Button' issue and how to resolve it?

**System Details**

1. **Photoshop Version:**  CS6
2. **Operating System:**  Windows 7 Home Premium
3. **Processor:**  Pentium Dual Core 2.30GHZ
4. **RAM:**  3GB

Comment: For starters, what version of Ps, what version of Windows?

Comment: Fair point.  Just added some extra details.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps you should repair PS from *Programs and Features". (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)